# Do I need to backup my GPG key again after extending its expiry date?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I have just extended the expiry date of my GPG key by following these instructions: [Can you extend the expiration date of an already expired GPG key?](https://superuser.com/questions/813421/can-you-extend-the-expiration-date-of-an-already-expired-gpg-key) I have previously backed-up my key. Do I need to backup again after extending its expiry date?

Comment: You can, but it's not critical since if you had to restore from backup, you can of course just renew the key again.  The expiration is largely a function of telling other people when you'd prefer them not to use the key.  It's not unlike a "best by" date on food.  i.e. "I _think_ based on current trends this key will be long enough to be used for 10 more years, signed Key Owner".

Comment: @SteveSether So if I encrypt a document using the renewed key, I'll be able to decrypt it using the expired key? Don't worry, I'll test it out, but I want some reassurance.

Comment: It's the same key.  All you're doing is putting a new signature with a different expiration date on they key.